# How to solve function f(x,y) for either x or y (if the other is given)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, symbolic-math, equation-solving, mathjs

I started to work with [`mathjs`](http://mathjs.org/) and tried to rewrite some Python code using [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for algebraic calculations. I implemented a fit function I got from a research article (see link in code snippet if interested) in code and need to rearrange/solve that equation for either the mole fraction (variable `x_1`) or the density (variable `rho`).

As shown in the [examples given in the docs](http://mathjs.org/examples/expressions.js.html) I defined the fit equation as a function of the two variables I am interested in like this:

```
const eqn = math.compile('f(x_1, rho) = param_1 + param_2 * temp + param_3 * rho + param_4 * rho^2 + param_5 * rho^(-1) + param_6 * temp * rho + param_7 * temp^(-1) - x_1')
```

In order to solve the fit equation for the variables I am interested in I defined two different scopes. Both of them contain the same constant parameters `param_1` to `param_7` and the temperature value `temp`. Since I want to use solve for `x_1` I need to provide the missing variable `rho` which I added to the first scope (`scope1`). To solve the equation for `rho` I added the missing variable `x_1` to the second scope (`scope2`).

With those explanations, my code looks like that:

```
const math = require('mathjs');

// physical properties and fit parameter
// fit from: 'doi:10.3390/fermentation4030072'
let scope1 = {
    // this scope is for solving the equation for `x_1`        
    param_1: -96.32780,     // -
    param_2: -0.02856512,   // 1/K
    param_3: 98.96611,      // cm3/g
    param_4: -37.81838,     // cm6/g2
    param_5: 35.07342,      // g/cm3
    param_6: 0.02844898,    // cm3/gK
    param_7: 36.74344,      // K
    temp: 293.15,
    rho: 0.93167,
}

let scope2 = {
    // this scope is for solving the equation for `rho`
    param_1: -96.32780,     // -
    param_2: -0.02856512,   // 1/K
    param_3: 98.96611,      // cm3/g
    param_4: -37.81838,     // cm6/g2
    param_5: 35.07342,      // g/cm3
    param_6: 0.02844898,    // cm3/gK
    param_7: 36.74344,      // K
    temp: 293.15,
    x_1: 0.224269,
}

const eqn = math.compile('f(x_1, rho) = param_1 + param_2 * temp + param_3 * rho + param_4 * rho^2 + param_5 * rho^(-1) + param_6 * temp * rho + param_7 * temp^(-1) - x_1')

// compiled expression/equation needs to be solved for `x_1`
const res1 = eqn.eval(scope1)
console.log(res1)

// compiled expression/equation needs to be solved for `rho`
const res2 = eqn.eval(scope2)
console.log(res2)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
{ [Function: f] signatures: { 'any,any': [Function] }, syntax: 'f(x_1, rho)' }
{ [Function: f] signatures: { 'any,any': [Function] }, syntax: 'f(x_1, rho)' }
```

How do I get the results out of the results `res1` or `res2`, respectively?

Comment: Have you tried `res1(1,2)`, `res2(1,2)`? - syntax: 'f(x_1, rho)'

Comment: This would mean that both `x_1` and `rho` are known to calculate the corresponding result. However, I need to substitute the known variable with its value and calculate the other.

Comment: as far as i can see you need two different equations for either x_1 or rho to be unknown